# How to block an operation in a thread, an resume it on the signal in Linux without a condition variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to write a faulty code that doesn't uses the pthread_cond variable. On the condition check, if the condition fails it waits/blocks forever. The thread B should post a signal to get the thread A unblock. I don't the API to use for block and unblock in Linux.
I want to demonstrate the conditional variable benefits. However, I want to first write a code that blocks on a condition, and it should unblock by the signal. In this, I will show how a signal is lost, and the race condition occurs.Please help me with the API's and usage.

Comment: You could implement a busy-wait loop?

Comment: I think you are asking about `sigsuspend`.

Comment: I am using pause function to block it. How to unblock this function? I tried this function, but it is not able to unblock it -   kill(pid_A, SIGCONT);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pthread_mutex instead.
First create a global mutex, and lock it into your main() function before creating the threads A & B.
Into thread A do a pthread_mutex_lock() that will wait until the mutex is unlocked.
Into thread B do a pthread_mutex_unlock() to signal your thread A to continue.